# ¿Es normal que el combobox se presente de esa manera? c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms, combobox, autocompletar

tengo una duda, porque el combobox, cuando se presnta de esa manera, acabo de implementar el automplete, pero al parecer cuando el combo esta lleno, me indica todo el combo ocupando la pantall, hay alguna forma de que esta se desplegue solo hacia abajo. y no me ocupe toda la pantalla.?
gracias,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola JuanL, las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Por favor, edita la pregunta para añadir el código que genera el combobox así como las propiedades que pudieran afectar su representación. Lee [ask] y [mcve] para más información y consejos.

Comment: Como comenta @AlvaroMontoro haría falta más información para saber el motivo por el que te aparece así. En principio el control muestra las opciones en una posición u otra en función de la cantidad de información a presentar. Si te aparece en blanco como en la pantalla habría que ver porqué, y si es que tienes muchas opciones para seleccionar (y has borrado esta info porque no deseas compartirla) deberías pensar otra forma de implementar el interfaz. Un combo con tantas opciones no es práctico. Si es un autocomplete podrías limitar el nº de respuestas a mostrar.

Comment: Intenta ajustar el tamaño de `ComboBox.MaxDropDownHeight`

Comment: Lo que está en blanco del combobox es seleccionable?

Comment: que tal, @Luis basicamente, esa opccion es de autocomplete, y lo que intento hace es que no me muestre todo lo del combobox  en la vista, si no que debajo del combo.